# Making a call to Cloud Firestore before Widget is rendered

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Grid with a bunch of items (like meals) and whenever I want to edit an item I click a button and a bottom sheet opens which looks like the following:
[image]

Now this is rendered from a static list in a dart file. I want to change the following code snippet so that my Cloud Firestore content is rendered:

```
    var _isInit = true;
    var _isLoading = false;

    @override
    void initState() {
    _imageUrlFocusNode.addListener(_updateImageUrl);
    super.initState();
    }
    @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit == true) {
      final mealId = widget.id;
      if (mealId != null) {
        _editedMeal = Meals().findById('1'); //THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO RETRIEVE DATA FROM CLOUD FIRESTORE
        _initValues = {
          'title': _editedMeal.title,
          'recipe': _editedMeal.recipe,
          'description': _editedMeal.description,
          'imageUrl': '',
        };
        _imageUrlController.text = _editedMeal.imageUrl;
      }
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

I need to change that part where there comment is to Firestore as a data source. I was able to retrieve the data with this statement but it is not fast enough to render so I only see blank TextFormFields and no image. This is the code I tried it with and got the data but wasn't able to render anything:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('meals').doc(mealId).get().then((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          _editedMeal = Meal(
            id: document.id,
            //...
          );
        });
```

This code was used instead of the static one where the comment was:

```
_editedMeal = Meals().findById('1'); //THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO RETRIEVE DATA
```

Can someone please provide a solution on how to load the data dynamically from Firestore and fill this "_editedMeal" before the Widget renders.

Thank you

Comment: Where are you calling `get()`? Anyway most probably you need to call `setState()` which would call the `build()` method and update the state of `_editedMeal`

Comment: Where would call setState()? get() is called to get the data from the document retrieved by firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually used a work around. It doesn't really do what I asked for but I am just passing the already existent parameters to the bottom sheet and render those without grabbing data again from Firestore